# Is there any way to receive event when new client connect and disconnect?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

We are using node as a server and mqtt as a library.

we installed mosquitto as a brocker for web socket.

Now we have to track record when new client connect and disconnect but problem is that we unable to get any event.

so Is there any way to achieve this ?

```
const mqttServer = require('mqtt');

const clientId = appName + "_" + moment().valueOf();
const conOptions = {
    clientId,
    username: mqtt.user,
    password: mqtt.pass,
    keepalive: 10,
    clean: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const conUrl = mqtt.uri;
const mqttClient = mqttServer.connect(conUrl, conOptions);

mqttClient.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error(`${chalk.red('✗')} MQTT Error : `, err);
});

mqttClient.on('offline', () => {
    logger.error(`${chalk.red('✗')} MQTT Offline`);
});

mqttClient.on('reconnect', () => {
    logger.error(`${chalk.red('✗')} MQTT Reconnect`);
});

mqttClient.on('connect', () => {
    logger.info(`${chalk.green('✓')} MQTT Connected with ClientID ${chalk.yellow(clientId)}`);
});

mqttClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    logger.error(`New message in MQTT : ${message.toString()} on ${topic}`);
});
```

Comment: So everything works but you don't get the log message implemented in `connect` event? (I don't see the `disconnect` in sample code)

Comment: No, I want to get event when other client connect or disconnect.

Comment: That data is only available to the broker (server you connects to) not the publisher/subscriber (the code you posted). For example using [mosca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mosca) you get that event in `clientConnected` event.

Comment: Can you please describe how we can use mosca ?

Comment: There are [tutorials](https://medium.com/@alifabdullah/setting-up-private-mqtt-broker-using-mosca-in-node-js-c61a3c74f952) for it on web but having your broker adds extra work and maintenance too. Using @hardillb solution you can get the `connect` info for sure and `disconnect` info if the broker is under your control or publishes `disconnect` info on client's behalf (if not ask for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have each client publish their own message when they connect/disconnect.

This allows you to control exactly what is in the message.

You can send the disconnect message before you tell the client to disconnect.

Also you can also make use of the Last Will & Testament to have the broker publish (after the KeepAlive has expired) a message on the client's behalf if it is disconnected due to a crash/network failure.

This technique will work with any browser.

Comment: when I'm trying to add
```notifications true```
then mosquitto is not starting even if I set
```log_dest file_path```
then it also not starting 

can you help us that what error should be ?

Comment: That's a totally different question to what you asked here. Ask a new question, include the config file you are using and the errors that are shown